# parsing json from google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, jsonparser

I'm trying to parse a Json file stored on google drive

Here my code to get the json to parse:

```
function readFile(fileName) {
  var fileName = filenane;
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    setdata(json);
  }
}
```

json response: [Json response](https://lovesdata.000webhostapp.com/json_to_parse)

Here my attempt to parse the json response

```
function setdata(json) {
     var rows = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      for(var s = 0; s < json[i].result.organic_results; s++) {
        //your JSON entities here
        rows.push([json[i].result.search_parameters.q,json[i].result.organic_results[s].position ]);
      }
    }
    Logger.log(rows);
}
```

**Issue**: the "rows" array is empty

Any help?

Comment: Please post the complete JSON string

Comment: @Cooper I posted the JSON response in the link due to the body of my question is limited to 30000 characters.

Comment: I don't follow links off of this site.  Please provide a representative sample of the string. It's your responsibility to provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? I thought that in your script, at `for(var s = 0; s < json[i].result.organic_results; s++) {` of 2nd loop, it is required to modify from `json[i].result.organic_results` to `json[i].result.organic_results.length`. When `for(var s = 0; s < json[i].result.organic_results; s++) {` is used, the script in the 2nd loop is not run. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

So please modify as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
for(var s = 0; s < json[i].result.organic_results; s++) {
```

#### To:

```
for(var s = 0; s < json[i].result.organic_results.length; s++) {
```